# How to set the download directory in docker selenium

Tags: python, docker, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have an issue.

The issue is, ı'm developing a project with Python. The project is web scraping. I'm using a selenium library.

With the Selenium library, I click a button and download the relevant file(xlsx etc).
Check following sample code:

```
    driver = webdriver.Remote('http://selenium:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
    driver.get("link")
    cdate=time.strftime('%Y%m%d')  
    print(cdate)
    while True:
        try:
            wait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='{}']".format(cdate)))).click()
            print("Found, succes!")
            time.sleep(3)
            break
        except:
            f = '%Y%m%d'
            cdate = (datetime.strptime(cdate, f) - timedelta(days=1)).strftime(f)
            print("Not match")
            time.sleep(3)
            print(str(cdate))
```

When I tried to Dockerize my own code it worked successfully. I entered the relevant place with the code below. I found the downloaded file in the directory below.

```
docker exec -it <container name> bash
cd /Downloads
ll Sample.xlsx
```

I need a change download directory. When the docker container up,I want to download it to my own computer. (Like this: c:\Desktop...)

Docker-Compose.yaml

```
    version: '3'

services:
    selenium:
        image: selenium/standalone-chrome
        ports: 
        - 4444:4444
        restart: always
    app:
        build:
            context: .
        volumes: 
        - ./app:/app
        command: sh -c "python3 dev2.py"
        depends_on: 
            - selenium
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DISPLAY=:99

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a volume to your selenium container that would be mapping your host to container folder so that your volumes would look like:

```
selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    ports: 
    - 4444:4444
    restart: always
    volumes: 
    - /path/to/host/folder:/Downloads
```

So all files which your container process would put to `/Downloads` would appear in `/path/to/host/folder` of your host.

Comment: Thanks for reply but problem is still. I share with you the code below
        volumes: 
        - ./app:/app
        - ./currentDownload:/Downloads

Comment: Updated my answer. You need to add a volume to Selenium container, not to the container where you are running your tests.